# Finding a basis which is orthonormal with respect to symmetric bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

Let $X=\{a\in M_4(\mathbb{C}): a^T=-a\}$ be the $6$-dimensional vector space of matrices. Define the Pfaffian as
$$ \mathrm{Pf}(a)=a_{12}a_{34}-a_{13}a_{24}+a_{14}a_{23} $$
There is an associated bilinear form defined by polarisation $B=\frac{1}{4}(\mathrm{Pf}(a+b)-\mathrm{Pf}(a-b))$. Suppose I want to find a basis for $X$ which is orthonormal relative to $B$; that is, a basis $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6\}$ such that $B(a_i,a_j)=\begin{cases} \pm1\mbox{ if } i=j \\ 0 \mbox{ if }i\neq j\end{cases}$. Now, it is clear to me what the first three elements of the most obvious basis are:
$$ a_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 &  0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, a_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, a_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
But I've got no idea how to complete this to the full basis. It is possible to extend this to any basis and then perform a modified version of the Gram-Schmidt process, but is it maybe possible to "read off" the basis elements from the definitions of $\mathrm{Pf}$ and $B$?

Comment: (Is $B$ obviously an inner product?) Why not start with the basis $e_i e_j^T - e_j e_i^T$ ($i=1,2,3$, $j>i$), and use Gram Schmidt with $B$ as the inner product?

Comment: $B$ is not an inner product, it is not positive-definite.

Comment: $B$ is symmetric, so it can be diagonalized. But if it is not $>0$, then you will have $B(v,v) \le 0$ for some $v$ in this basis.

Comment: So, it is not possible to have a basis with $B(v,v)=1$ for all $v$ in this basis? What if we allow $B(v,v)=\pm1$ and $B(v,w)=0$?

Comment: Sure, let $u_k$ be a diagonalizing basis for $B$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_k$, then choose the basis $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\lambda_k|}} u_k$. (Assuming $B$ is invertible.)

Comment: @copper.hat, thanks, I was confused because I was looking for a basis where $B(v,v)=1$, but now, allowing $B(v,v)=\pm 1$ I see what this basis looks like.

Comment: There is no need to perform a Gram-Schmidt process. If you flatten $A$ as a $6$-vector, where the entries of $A$ are arranged in lexiographic order of the $i,j$ indices, then the matrix of $B$ is just one half of the antidiagonal matrix with $(1,-1,1,1,-1,1)$ on the antidiagonal. So you may obtain the eigenvectors immediately.